# Homepage в Magento

Tags: magento

Столкнулся с проблемой. Она заключается в следующем: при нажатии на лого или же на вкладку "Главная" выводится ссылка формата http://sitename.ru/ . Как бы все хорошо, но, если ввести http://sitename.ru/home, то выдает ту же главную страницу, только с приставкой /home. Выходит, что у меня на сайте две одинаковых страницы и гугл кричит ахтунг - это плохо. в чем проблема, не могу понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не проблема а так оно и есть. Настройте редирект с `http://sitename.ru/home` до `http://sitename.ru/` это можно сделать в админке в `каталог -> управление урл -> добавить` в селекте тип выбираем другой, и следуем дальше по подсказкам полей и сохраняем.